# get subclasses of a class OwlApi

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

There is a way to find all named subclasses of a class without using a reasoner  `for (OWLClass child : reasoner.getSubClasses(clazz, true).getFlattened() )` and without doing inference just by using axioms? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using owl-api the ontology can be query to get all subClasses axioms.
Then you filter the result to retain only the named classes.

```
for (final OWLSubClassOfAxiom subClasse : ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF))
{
    if (subClasse.getSuperClass() instanceof OWLClass 
         && subClasse.getSubClass() instanceof OWLClass)
    {
        System.out.println(subClasse.getSubClass() 
             + " extends " + subClasse.getSuperClass());
    }
}
```

Using Jena, you can list statement, add look for the "subClassOf" predicate, then as in owl-api you filter to get only non-annoymous objects.

```
final StmtIterator it = model.listStatements();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    final Statement s = it.next();
    if (s.getPredicate().equals(RDFS.subClassOf) && !s.getObject().isAnon())
            System.out.println(s.getSubject() + " extends " + s.getObject());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. however, it doesn't take into account relationships between classes and the first level class which is Thing. I understand, because in the owl.file there is no reference to show that those classes are subclasses of Thing it's done by the reasoner. There is no way to take them into account without using reasoner? I hope that ...

Comment: Make a set(A) of all sub classes seen that aren't sub classes of Thing.
Take the set(B) of all classes in signature and remove classes from(A).
The remaining of B should be an additionnal set of classes that are direcly subClasses of Thing.